# split the string which has hypen

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know how to split and get the values in the following variable

```
var str= "send-money-from-united-states-to-hong-kong"
var str1= "send-money-from-thailand-to-singapore"
```

Expected Output: `United States Hong Kong`

Expected Output: `Thailand Singapore`

Comment: what've you tried? [mcve] please

Comment: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regular expression here.

This simple code will extract wanted data:

```js
var strArr = "send-money-from-thailand-to-singapore".replace("send-money-from-", "").split("-");
for (i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) { 
  // capitalize letters
  strArr[i] = strArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArr[i].slice(1);
}
var countries = strArr.join(" ").split(" To ");
console.log(countries[0]);
console.log(countries[1]);
```

I assumed that strings are in the same format: starting with `send-money-from-` and countries are divided by `-to-`.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply but is there any way to store it in array like ["United States", "Hong Kong"] and ["Thailand", "Singapore"], if possible please help @Michal Turczyn

Comment: @sowmiya Try updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the following js.

Could be simplified, but made it stepwise for better understading:

```js
var str = "send-money-from-united-states-to-hong-kong"

str = str.replace("send-money-from-", "");
str = str.replace("-to-", " ");
str = str.replace(/-/g, " ");
str = str.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1)
}

console.log(str.join(" "));
```

Comment: Ah, missed that. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply but is there any way to store it in array like ["United States", "Hong Kong"] and ["Thailand", "Singapore"], if possible please help

Answer (score -1):

Using the split function from javascript will help

```
var strArr = str.split('-')
```

You'll get an array that you can then manipulate to your liking. So for your expected output you'll want to concatenate the indexes that you require.

```
var strArr = str.split('-')
var strArr2 = str2.split('-')
console.log(strArr[4], strArr[5], strArr[6], strArr[7])
console.log(strArr2[3], strArr2[5])
```

Then using a custom function, you can get a title

```
String.prototype.toProperCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
};
```

```
strArr[2].toProperCase()
```

Lodash can make this manipulation minimized such as:

```
var strArr = _.map(_.split(str), function(text) { return _.startCase(text) })
```

And then get the necessary values. In terms of manipulating the array to get the correct values from the string, you will need some sort of template array that has the text that you will accept.

Then you can map through the string array against that template array and only accept the values that fulfill a true condition.

```
// Remember evaluating case when creating array (LowerCase vs TitleCase)
var templateArray = ['Thailand', 'Singapore']
var strArr = _.map(_.split(str), function(text) { return _.startCase(text) })

var reducer = function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    if(templateArray.includes(currentValue)) {
        accumulator.push(currentValue)
    }
}

var newString = strArr.reduce(reducer, [])
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @Olufemi Adesina if i  use split("-") i will get united and states seperately, if possible help.thanks

Comment: Added a few edits
Not the most elegant way (Formatting can be done way better) but this will get what the user wanted.

So how did you want array done. Using a library like lodash here can help to minimize code like this. Are you willing to use an external library?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Was aware, just made some edits to it.